# JSON parse in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm bit new to Javascript. This seems silly question. Im trying to parse JSON in the Nextjs Main function. When I try to parse JSON in main function before return statement, it shows error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

```
export default function Home() {
    const countries = JSON.parse({"data":{"countries":[{"name":"Canada"}]}})
    return (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(countries)}</pre>
    )
}
```

#### UPDATE

*On Question Details*

The earlier comment indeed solves the question earlier asked. Thank you @boop_the_snoot and @Anvay .However, that's not exactly the issue I'm trying to reproduce the error.

I've nextjs route `[forecastCategory]/[xquote]/[forecastid].js` with following code:

```
import {pathsData} from "@/components/Data"


export default function ForecastID({ stocksString}) {
    //var myStocks = JSON.parse(stocksString)
    return (
      <>
      
      <pre>{stocksString}</pre>
      
    </>
  );
}


export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  // HERE JSON STRING DIRECT ENTRY.
  var stocksDataTemp = {
    "daily-forecast--1": {
      "DFP4362832": [
        "SJ78449",
        99,
        21,
        99,
        "View",
        [
          {
            "name": "STOCK111",
            "LTP": 164.35,
            "BUY": 170,
            "SELL": 177,
            "GAIN": 3.95
          }
        ]
      ],
      "DFP1329702": [
        "SJ59264",
        98,
        21,
        96,
        "View",
        [
          {
            "name": "STOCK112",
            "LTP": 475.1,
            "BUY": 484,
            "SELL": 497,
            "GAIN": 2.62
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "daily-forecast--2": {
      "DFP8899451": [
        "SJ49453",
        99,
        21,
        98,
        "View",
        [
          {
            "name": "STOCK113",
            "LTP": 1787.25,
            "BUY": 1894,
            "SELL": 1935,
            "GAIN": 2.12
          },
          {
            "name": "STOCK114",
            "LTP": 467.3,
            "BUY": 481,
            "SELL": 493,
            "GAIN": 2.43
          }
        ]
      ],
      "DFP9681539": [
        "SJ54067",
        97,
        25,
        91,
        "View",
        [
          {
            "name": "STOCK115",
            "LTP": 194.5,
            "BUY": 201,
            "SELL": 211,
            "GAIN": 4.74
          },
          {
            "name": "STOCK116",
            "LTP": 1461.15,
            "BUY": 1563,
            "SELL": 1612,
            "GAIN": 3.04
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }

  const xquote = ctx.params.xquote;
  console.log("xquote:",xquote)
  const quoteCount = xquote.split("-", 1)[0];
  console.log("quoteCount:",quoteCount)
  const forecastCategorySlug = ctx.params.forecastCategory;
  console.log("forecastCategorySlug:",forecastCategorySlug)
  const forecastid = ctx.params.forecastid; 
  console.log("forecastid:",forecastid)

  var stocksPageData = stocksDataTemp[forecastCategorySlug + "--" + quoteCount][forecastid];
  console.log("stocksString:",stocksString)
  var stocksPageDataString = JSON.stringify(stocksPageData);
  var stocksString = JSON.stringify(stocksPageData[5])
  console.log("stocksString:",stocksString)
  //var countriesString = JSON.stringify({"data":{"countries":[{"name":"Canada"}]}})

  return {
    props: {
      stocksString,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async (ctx) => {
...
}
```

The above code on the route `/daily-forecast/1-quote/DFP4362832` produce the following:

```
[{"name":"STOCK111","LTP":164.35,"BUY":170,"SELL":177,"GAIN":3.95}]
```

However, when I uncomment `var myStocks = JSON.parse(stocksString)` it produce the earlier JSON parse error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` I'm still not able to figure out the JSON parsing issue.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Nextjs! `JSON.parse({"data":{"countries":[{"name":"Canada"}]}})` is wrong, because its already a valid JSON, instead of a string. Do `JSON.stringify({"data":{"countries":[{"name":"Canada"}]}})`, thats it

Comment: @boop_the_snoot, I'm getting json in the form of string from getStaticProps() and trying to parse in main function. As for the example, you can assume, `var countriesString = JSON.stringify({"data":{"countries":[{"name":"Canada"}]}})` in getStaticProps() and variable countriesString passed via props.

Comment: if thats the case, follow the answer by @anway, and switch variables/values wherever necessary

Comment: @L.fole JSON.parse is to convert a string to a valid JavaScript object. However, what you are right now doing is already inputting a valid JavaScript object into the JSON.parse, which is not necessary. You can delete that code, because what you are trying to do is parsing an already parsed object.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using `JSON.parse()`, which is correct. However, `JSON.parse` takes in *only* a string, so to solve that you can change your code to this:

```js
export default function Home() {
    const countries = JSON.parse("{\"data\":{\"countries\":[{\"name":"Canada\"}]}}")
    return (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(countries)}</pre>
    )
}
```

Remember to escape the quotes! It is not considered valid JSON to use single quotes for the text.

Answer (score 0):

**my simple solution is:**

```
export const parseJson = (data) => {
    let item;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // Perform localStorage action
        item = JSON.parse(data)
    }
    return item
};
```